# matplotlib fails to output EPS figure with usetex = True

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, eps

I am trying to output (`savefig`) matplotlib figures as EPS; however, it seems there is a conflict when using the LaTeX rendering AND saving EPS figures. For example, the following code produces a **good** EPS figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.random.rand(100))
plt.savefig('plot.eps')
```

[image]

whereas this code produces an EPS figure that can not be viewed; my document viewer (Ubuntu's Evince) continuously says "Loading..."

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rc('text', usetex = True)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.random.rand(100))
plt.savefig('plot.eps')
```

[image]

Is there a known issue when combining these two options? Is there any kind of work around (aside from saving as PDF or saving as PDF then converting to EPS)?

Comment: will it open with inkscape?

Comment: @tcaswell No, Inkscape failed to open it, returning the error: "ps2pdf failed"

Comment: what version of `mpl` and `latex`?

Comment: and can you put the eps someplace?

Comment: @tcaswell mpl: 1.2.1, texlive: 20130772-1, and eps: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sld8jw5n1uepngb/plot.eps

Comment: Well, I updated matplotlib to 1.3.1 and it now has no problem outputting (working) eps images with usetex = True. As always, thanks for the help!

Comment: You should post an answer saying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I could find was to update matplotlib from 1.2.1 to 1.3.1. Now it works without problems.